# Wordpress Pagination 404 error on homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I'm having problem with Wordpress pagination links on my homepage. 
The function next_posts_link() return me this link:

```
Link: www.mysite.com/page/2
Result: Nothing Found for Page 2
```

But, if i go to this link..

```
Link: www.mysite.com?page=2
Result: Foo | Foo - Part 2 OK!!
```

PD: I'm using ALL in One SEO plugin, and my permalink config is: "/%category%/%postname%/"

Comment: Not a wordpress expert, but I would try either adding a trailing slash here `www.mysite.com/page/2` or removing it here `/%category%/%postname%/`

Comment: Nop, i tried all options and nothing..